# Why Does get_page_by_path Return The Sample Post?

Tags: pages, footer

I'm trying to check if a page exists, if it is published, and display a list item with the link to the page if it is. Here's my code:

```
  <?php
    $page = get_page_by_path('/privacy-policy/', OBJECT, 'page');

    if ( get_post_status($page->post_status) == 'publish' ):
  ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_title('Privacy Policy') ); ?>">Privacy Policy</a>
  </li>
  <?php
    endif;

    $page = get_page_by_path('/terms-of-use/', OBJECT, 'page');

    if ( get_post_status($page->post_status) == 'publish' ):
  ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_title('Terms of Use') ); ?>">Terms of Use</a>
  </li>
  <?php
    endif;

    $page = get_page_by_path('/sitemap/', OBJECT, 'page');

    if ( get_post_status($page->post_status) == 'publish' ):
  ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_title('Sitemap') ); ?>">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

It hides the first link because there's a sample Privacy Policy page that isn't published but it displays the other two with a link to the sample post. I haven't created the dummy page for the last two yet.

Comment: FYI [the `get_page_by_title()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) has been deprecated.

Comment: Yeah. I found out. I changed it to get_page_by_path. Then, I finally discovered that the more proper way to do what I want to happen is to register a new menu in the functions.php of my theme. So, I'm going that way. I'm new to WordPress.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted, as it is the answer to your question, even though not your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page doesn't exist, then `get_page_by_title()` returns `null`, which when passed into `get_page_link()` still returns a URL, which could conceivably redirect to the sample post. Check the value of `get_page_by_title()` is valid before using.